# pulling row number into query google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set that looks like this: starting on A1 with "1"

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Column A is an arrayformula =arrayformula(row(b1:b))
Column B is manual input

i want to query the database and finding the row of the item by match column B so i have code as such

```
=query("A1:B","select A where B like '%c%')
```

this should give me "3"

My question:

is there a way to pull the 1-4 numbers into the query line? with something like array formula row(b1:b). I don't want to waste an extra column on column A

so basically I want just the manual input and when i query it gives me the row number.

No script code please.

I've tried a few things and it didn't work.

Looking for a solutions that starts with

```
=query()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a formula to pull in more than one row in the dataset which matches the condition, if this is important to you:

```
=arrayformula(filter(row(B:B); B:B="c"))
```

And you can have wildcard type operators, under certain circumstances (you are going to match text or items that can look like text (so numbers can be treated as text - but boolean will need more steps); that the dataset is not huge), using regular expressions.  e.g.

```
=arrayformula(filter(row(B:B); regexmatch(B:B, "(c|d)")))
```

You could also use standard spreadsheet wildcard operators, e.g.

```
=arrayformula(filter(row(B:B); countif(B:B, "*c*")))
```

Explanation: In this case, the filter will be true when countif is greater than zero, i.e. when it sees something with a letter c in it, since spreadsheets see a value greater than zero as a boolean true and so, for that row where there is a countif match, there will be a a filter match, and so it will display that row (indeed, it is a similar situation with the regexmatch creating a true when there is a match of either c or d, in the case above).

Personally, I wanted to learn regex a bit, so I would go towards the regexmatch option.  But that is your choice.

You can also, of course, create the match outside of the cell. This makes it easy to create a list of matches that you want to satisfy elsewhere on the sheet. So you could have a column of words or parts of words, from Z2 downwards, and then join them together in cell Z1 for example like this

```
="("&join("|",filter(Z2:Z50,len(Z2:Z50)))&")"
```

Then your filter function would look like this:

```
=arrayformula(filter(row(B:B), regexmatch(B:B, Z1)))
```

If you want to use like operator in the query  function, you can try something like this:

```
=arrayformula(query(if({1,0}, B:B,row(B:B)),"select Col2 where Col1 like '%c%' "))
```

You can also use the regular expressions in the query function, for example:

```
=arrayformula(query(if({1,0}, B:B,row(B:B)),"select Col2 where Col1 matches '(.*c.*|.*d.*)' "))
```

Comment: can you use wildcards in filter? just like in query?

Comment: You can add regular expressions to the 2nd argument as one option.  I have modified the answer to show this.

Comment: I have edited for query function with row operator and wildcards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on the question, but as I understand it, you want to be able to enter a formula, and have it return the row number of the matched item in a range? I'm not sure where array formulas come in.

If I've understood your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
=MATCH("C",B1:B,0)
```

In your example, this returns `3`.

Please forgive me if I've misunderstood your question.

**Note:** If there are multiple matches, this will return the row number for the first instance of your search.

Comment: i've change the question, i realized i made the problem too simple. match doesn't work, because I'm looking for a query function that uses  wildcards. I need something that is not an exact match

Answer (score -2):

```
=QUERY({A1:A,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A))},"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%c%'")
```

Comment: Please explain your solution

Comment: As suggested by DebanjanB and BookOfZeus, additional information should be provided.